# Why do I get MissingResourceException

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Why does this throw a MissingResourceException ? Am I mistaken or is that not 
the point of ListResourceBundles is to provide the resources in code?

```
public class Hello extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         ResourceBundle resBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ResourceBundle", new Locale("it", "IT", ""));
         System.out.println(resBundle.getObject(new Integer(1).toString()));
    }


}
```

in a seperate file:

```
public class ResourceBundle_it_IT extends ListResourceBundle {

    public Object[][] getContents() {
        return contents;
    }
    static final Object[][] contents = {
        {"1", "Uno"},
        {"2", "Duo"},
        {"3", "Trie"},};

}
```

My Error:

```
 run:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ResourceBundle, locale it_IT
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
    at hello.Hello.main(Hello.java:21)
/home/maxbisesi/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an error, and try to understand the reason, the first step is **always** to read the stack trace of the error. In this case, the stack trace is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ResourceBundle, locale it_IT
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
    at Hello.main(Hello.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java.util.ResourceBundle$Control can not access a member of class ResourceBundle_it_IT with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2645)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1501)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1465)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1361)
    ... 2 more
```

And if you read it, the problem becomes obvious:

> Class java.util.ResourceBundle$Control can not access a member of class ResourceBundle_it_IT with modifiers ""

Move the class ResourceBundle_it_IT to its onwn file, where it belongs. make it public as the error message suggests, and the problem disappears.

Comment: I moved the Bundle into its own file as a public class and still get the same error?

Comment: What is the package of the ResourceBundle_it_IT class?

Comment: 'hello' same as the main

Comment: Then the base name for your bundle is "hello.ResourceBundle". Not "ResourceBundle".

Answer (score 0):

Usually happens when the class that represents your resource is not public, since property values need to be public to be scanned, check if your class is properly marked `public`

Answer (score 0):

// in ResBundle.java file

```
 package ocpjp8.locale;
public class ResBundle extends ListResourceBundle {}
```

// in some other java file

ResourceBundle.getBundle("ocpjp8.locale.ResBundle");

// need to give package name + class name